# How can I get all the information from an address that has multiple Places_id

Tags: web-services, google-places-api

I send a HTTP request, with only the address, I do not know the name of the place/company. I get a Place Id, but it does not give me any additional information. However, if I send an HTTP request with the same address, and the name of the building/company, I get another place id, at the same location, but here I get all the additional info that Places provides.

But I have to find the place only by the address. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to make this work, or how do I get the name of the building at the address out, Places does not give out a name when I only enter the address.

This is the input with the name and address, from the location

[image: This is the input with the name and address, from the location]

These additional infos I get to the Place ID, at name + address

[image: These additional infos I get to the Place ID, at name + address]

This is the input with only the address, from the location

[image: This is the input with only the address, from the location]

These additional infos I get to the Place ID,from only the address

[image: These additional infos I get to the Place ID,from only the address]

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot you provided shows that you have set the `fields` parameter to only get the name, business_status and place id. I suggest you take a look [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/place-data-fields) to see the list of available data/fields that can be retrieved.

I am not entirely sure what Places SKU/requests you are making, but removing the `fields` parameter will allow you to retrieve all the data. Do note that you will be billed accordingly for Contact and Atmosphere Data. Basic Data is free of charge.

Lastly, place ids are unique, and each address can only have one. You may want to make use of [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) to see a list of suggested addresses and check which one you are looking for. After which, you can pass its place id to a [Place Details request](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) to get information on that place.